# Kotlin for Volley, how can I check the JSON request for newer data in the API?

Tags: kotlin, gson, android-volley, android-notifications

I'm working on an app that gets a list of documents/source URL from an api.  I'd like to periodically check for new or updated contents within that API so users can update saved items in the database.  I'm at a loss on the correct wording to search, thus Google and Stack Overflow have both failed me.  My fetching function is below:

The URL for the API is https://api.afiexplorer.com

```
    private fun fetchPubs() {
        _binding.contentMain.loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        request = JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            Config.BASE_URL,
            JSONArray(),{ response ->
                val items: List<Pubs> =
                    Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), object : TypeToken<List<Pubs>>() {}.type)

                val sortedItems = items.sortedWith(compareBy { it.Number })

                pubsList?.clear()
                pubsList?.addAll(sortedItems)

                // Hardcoded pubs moved to Publications Gitlab Repo
                // https://gitlab.com/afi-explorer/pubs

                _binding.contentMain.recyclerView.recycledViewPool.clear()
                adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                _binding.contentMain.loading.visibility = View.GONE
                setupData()
                Log.i("LENGTH OF DATA", "${items.size}")

            },
            {error ->
                println(error.printStackTrace())
                Toasty.error(applicationContext, getString(string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show()
            }
        )
        MyApplication.instance.addToRequestQueue(request!!)
    }

    private fun setupData(){
        adapter = MainAdapter(applicationContext, pubsList!!, this)
        _binding.contentMain.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

I tried using ChatGPT to see if that would get me started and that failed miserably.  Also searched Google, Reddit and Stack Overflow for similar projects, but mine is a unique scenario I guess. I'm just a hobbyist and intermediate dev I guess. First time working with Volley, everything works, but I would like to find a way to send a notification (preferably not Firebase) if there is updated info within the API listed above.  I'm not sure if this is actually doable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can somehow find if the remote API has changed its content?  If so, how would that service advise you?  If the service provider provides a web hook or similar callback you could write a server-based program to send a push notification to your Android app.

Perhaps you intent to **poll** the API periodically, and then you want to know if there is a change?

1. If you use a tool such as Postman or `curl` to easily see the headers of the API https://api.afiexplorer.com you will see, unfortunately, there is no `Last-Modified` header or `ETag` header which would allow you to easily determine if there was a change.
2. Next looking at the content of the API, the author does not provide an obvious version/change date, so no luck there.
3. What you could do is receive the content as a String, and perform a checksum operation on it, and if it differs you know there has been a change
4. or if you are deserialising the received JSON in Kotlin **data** classes, then out of the box, Kotlin will enable you to perform an equality operation on a previous copy of the data to know if there was a change.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an android app; if so, why don't you create a background service that makes requests to the API and updates the data as needed?  You can use an `AlarmManager` class to set the interval threshold for polling by using the `setInexactRepeating()` method.

Most apps are updated in this fashion; sometimes, a separate table is created to catalog changesets.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's an Android app.  I just realized I forgot to include that.